# How to run jetty from within intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

How can I start up a jersey or spring mvc app from intellij (ultimate edition) using jetty adn debug an api call and break on the end point?

I don't won't to setup a config and have to run $ mvnDebug jetty:run.

I'd like to click a button and have it start from my .war project.  Any ideas? thx.

[assume: I have jetty installed and plugin configured....i can run with mvnDebug jetty:run from cmd line and connect with debug session from intenllij but I occasionally get the following and they are annoying:

ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options.
Error occurred during initialization of VM]

Comment: You could use your Jetty Server in Intellij IDEA using a Run/Debug Configuration : **Run > Edit Configurations... > + > Jetty Server > Local**. Then you can add artifacts (war exploded) that will be deployed on your jetty and then simply launch it via _Debug_ ([doc here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-jetty.html)). Did you already try this ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can also add jetty plugin to maven:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then run maven command to start server and deploy application:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

Comment: ok, but will that allow me to set a breakpoint in the code and debug it?

Comment: Yes, of course, but if You want to do that just click on the Maven Prjects tab (on right side of IDE) in IntelliJ, choose Plugins -> jetty -> right click on jetty:run and choose debug  You can try it. Here is a example project: github.com/DanielMichalski/spring-web-blogs

Comment: mvn jetty:run is running my app. But unable to debug it as i could not find the option jetty under the plugins.

Comment: Try to click "Reimport all Maven Projects" on Maven Pane or:
Setttings -> Build, Execution, Deployments -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> Enable "Import Maven project automatically"