# MojoException- Vaadin Unable to compile

Tags: maven, deployment, vaadin

I'm currently trying to deploy and having a few problems. When running mvn compile in cmd it comes up with a Mojo error. I've attached my POM and the stack trace where the error occurs, any help would be appreciated. I'm using Intellij to build the WAR which will be deployed to a TOMCAT server and noted in the Vaadin 8 book that you need to compile your view classes into a JAR and place them in the app > Webapp > WEB-INF > classes folder, is there an automatic way of doing this? think this might be why the error is occuring? I'm pretty much at a loss and new to Vaadin development.

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>NewForest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>NewForest</name>
    <description>Payroll system</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>8.3.1</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>

        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>

        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    </dependencies>




    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/Webapp</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
    <display-name>MyApplication</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>New Forest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Vaadin UI</description>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.NewForest.NavigatorUI</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>New Forest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Error Stack trace:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\bin\java -Xmx1G -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war D:\Programming\NewForest\target\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets -localWorkers 12 -failOnError -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen D:\Programming\NewForest\target\.generated WEB-INF.images.archetype-application-example-master.mockapp-widgetset.src.main.resources.org.vaadin.mockapp.MockAppWidgetset
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:582)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\bin\java -Xmx1G -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war D:\Programming\NewForest\target\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets -localWorkers 12 -failOnError -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen D:\Programming\NewForest\target\.generated WEB-INF.images.archetype-application-example-master.mockapp-widgetset.src.main.resources.org.vaadin.mockapp.MockAppWidgetset
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:578)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: A simple way to compile and deploy your files is to add the jetty plugin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550740/how-to-run-jetty-from-within-intellij) to your pom.xml and write "mvn jetty:run" into your IntelliJ terminal.

Comment: thanks i should of mentioned that i'm looking to deploy it to a Tomcat server? Amended the question

Comment: Usually all you have to do is to place your WAR file in the tomcat/webapps folder and ensure, that tomcat is running. 

To create a WAR file, you can use "mvn clean install"

Comment: Yup that's what i'm doing but it's still presenting the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was shown in the stacktrace, in particular:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\bin\java -Xmx1G -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war D:\Programming\NewForest\target\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets -localWorkers 12 -failOnError -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen D:\Programming\NewForest\target\.generated WEB-INF.images.archetype-application-example-master.mockapp-widgetset.src.main.resources.org.vaadin.mockapp.MockAppWidgetset
]] failed with status 1
```

The widgetset it was trying to generate did not match that of Vaadin's Widgetset and as such caused a compile error. The answer was to delete the widgetset which meant the compiler defaulted to Vaadins widgetset.